# XWiki Servlet Exception

Tags: wiki, xwiki

I want to use XWiki for documenting some process, so I downloaded  xwiki-enterprise-installer-generic-5.0.1-standard.jar and installed it successfully. When i run the ./start_xwiki.sh file i am able to open xwiki in browser.

The problem what I am facing is when I try to upload any image in the edit page I get this message "There was an error loading the data", when i check logs it says 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to initialize the XWiki context.

can anyone help me in resolving this exception. Thanks in advance

Here is the stack trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to initialize the XWiki context.
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.initializeXWikiContext(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:153)
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.doFilter(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDavFilter.doFilter(XWikiDavFilter.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: 
com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 2 in 0: The wiki [leo] does not exist
    at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:505)
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.initializeXWikiContext(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:134)
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.doFilter(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDavFilter.doFilter(XWikiDavFilter.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-05-17 12:46:15.199:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/search
com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 2 in 0: The wiki [leo] does not exist
    at com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:505)
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.initializeXWikiContext(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:134)
    at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.XWikiContextInitializationFilter.doFilter(XWikiContextInitializationFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDav
```

Answer (score 2):

If the URL that you're using to access the wiki starts with `leo`, you might be affected by [this issue](http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-9150), which will be fixed in the upcoming 5.0.2 release.

Meanwhile, you can work around this by defining the URL for the wiki:

- open `/xwiki/bin/edit/XWiki/XWikiServerXwiki?editor=object`
- add an object of type `XWiki.XWikiServerClass`
- put the hostname (`leo`) in the `server` field
- save

It should work after that.

Comment: Yeah my url is leo:portno.. I am able to open the admin page and edit text but not able to upload any link or image, is there anything i can do to resolve this?